# Batch Convert All Folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard, directory

I have multiple folders with .jpg files in the input directory

- C:\MyFolders\AAA\001.jpg
- C:\MyFolders\AAA\002.jpg
- C:\MyFolders\BBB\001.jpg
- C:\MyFolders\BBB\002.jpg
- C:\MyFolders...

I want to convert all .jpg files and keep the same folder structure in the output directory

- C:\NewFolders\AAA\001.jpg
- C:\NewFolders\AAA\002.jpg
- C:\NewFolders\BBB\001.jpg
- C:\NewFolders\BBB\002.jpg
- C:\NewFolders...

`for /d %%f in (C:\MyFolders\*) do i_view32.exe "%%f\*.jpg" /resize=(1280,1280) /jpgq=75 /aspectratio /resample /convert=C:\NewFolders\%%d\*.jpg`

with the above code the conversion works but output folder is %d

- C:\NewFolders\%d\001.jpg
- C:\NewFolders\%d\002.jpg

with .jpg overwritten

Comment: Ok. So what isn't working?

Comment: the window closes immediately. it says syntax error / syntax can't be used here or something like that. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you converting from a jpg to a jpg? have you tried just doing a single file to see if it converts?

Comment: new try takes me further but not enough, updated code + explanation

Comment: where are you getting %%d from? Is there another for loop that the code you're showing is inside of?

Comment: no. thats all. %%d just because it converts with %%d but it also converts with %%q %%z or %%9.... %%f still doesnt work with this error: `JPG Save error! Can't open file for writing: "C:\NewFolders\C:\MyFolders\AAA\001.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that changing the metavariable used in the `FOR` to match the metavariable used in the `DO` may advance matters. Your posted code applies the directoryname to `%%f` but you are then using `%%d` in the `DO`.

That's only the start of your solution though. You'd probably need something like

```
for /r /d %%f in (C:\MyFolders\*) do ( for /f "tokens=1*delims=\" %%x in ("%%f") do (
  i_view32.exe "%%f\*.jpg" /resize=(1280,1280) /jpgq=75 /aspectratio /resample /convert=C:\NewFolders\%%x\*.jpg
 )
)
```